# How do you programmatically get a list of Google Forms (with ids) using Google Forms API?

Tags: scope, google-api, google-forms

I would like to know if it is possible to get the list of a Google Drive user's ***Forms*** (not the Docs, Spreadsheets, ...) using the Forms Service or the Google Drive API.

The reason why I am not sure is because there is no indication on how to do this on the [Forms Service page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/), and on the [Drive API's page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) the indications are very general. They don't take into account the fact that I will be using a OAuth2 token with a 'forms' scope and not a 'drive' scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* List all Google Forms in your Google Drive */
function getGoogleFormsList() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log("%s %s %s", file.getName(), file.getId(), file.getUrl());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        page_token = None
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        while True:
            response = drive_service.files().list(
                # You can use MIME types to filter query results
                q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.form'",
                spaces='drive',
                fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                pageToken=page_token
            ).execute()

            for file in response.get('files', []):
            # Process change
                print ('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break       

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```